# div width with tabel-cell display

Tags: html, css

I want to vertically align my buttons in a div. I'm using 'display: table-cell' and 'vertical-align: middle'. The problem is that the containing div is being shrunk down to the size of both buttons instead of maintaining its original width.

jsFiddle: [my table-cell demo](http://jsfiddle.net/8WVCA/)

html:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="bar">
<input type="button" value="Click Me">
<input type="button" value="Click Me">
</div>
<div>​
```

css:

```
.container{ width: 600px;}
.bar{
background-color: blue;
    //width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    display:table-cell;

    vertical-align: middle;
}.bar input{height: 60px;}
​
```

Comment: Your container is not actually getting shrinked. See this http://jsfiddle.net/8WVCA/4/

Answer (score 1):

You can apply `display:table-row` to the container:

Source: http://jsfiddle.net/Ktnq9/
Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Ktnq9/show

```
.container {
    width: 600px;
    table-layout: fixed;
    display: table-row;
}
```

Comment: This can be achieved also by adding following code to class bar !

    width:100%;

Comment: @SumitGera uh... what? No it can't.  That just results in the same code as the original fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/CCCMC/

Comment: oh sorry. I meant adding following in the container class.

    display:table;

And following in the bar class.

    width:100%;

Answer (score 1):

Add `display: table;` to `.container`.

Answer (score 0):

if you're not concerned with the or the container they are in having a variable height, you could also achieve this by adding an equally sized margin to the container, and removing table-cell refs:

```
.bar input{margin: 30px 0;}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/8WVCA/11/